# Unable to run Ta-Lib stuck in a looping future warning

Tags: python, ta-lib

Anyone can help on my issue?

environment
Python 3.10.11
Ta-lib installed

`df.ta.strategy(verbose=False, append=True)`

Keep looping below message and stuck forever:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py:48: FutureWarning: Series.getitem treating keys as positions is deprecated. In a future version, integer keys will always be treated as labels (consistent with DataFrame behavior). To access a value by position, use ser.iloc[pos]
return list(map(*args))
```

Have tried all ways to disable warnings

```
# Save the current warning settings
current_warnings = warnings.filters.copy()
# Suppress all warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
# Redirect standard output to null
sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
# Suppress logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
original_level = logger.getEffectiveLevel()
logger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL + 1)
# Suppress only FutureWarnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=all)
```

Comment: why not deal/fix the deprecation warning, instead of trying to hide it

Comment: It will worked  on Python 3.12.1

Comment: @ rioV8 there's nothing to deal with, it's just future warnings.
@toyota Supra great to hear about that, however I have issue installing ta-lib on other later python versions. I can only use up to 3.10 since I can only install with whl file.